# How do I sort the signal buses with bits in ascending order?

Tags: sort

I am trying to sort a file with signal buses. I am looking for result where the bits are in ascending order -- 2 followed by 3 and not 20.

```
cat file1 |sort

file1
cls_16_snap[2]
cls_16_snap[20]
cls_16_snap[21]
cls_16_snap[22]
cls_16_snap[23]
cls_16_snap[24]
cls_16_snap[25]
cls_16_snap[26]
cls_16_snap[27]
cls_16_snap[28]
cls_16_snap[29]
cls_16_snap[3]
cls_16_snap[30]
```

result

```
-------
cls_16_snap[2]
cls_16_snap[20]
cls_16_snap[21]
cls_16_snap[22]
cls_16_snap[23]
cls_16_snap[24]
cls_16_snap[25]
cls_16_snap[26]
cls_16_snap[27]
cls_16_snap[28]
cls_16_snap[29]
cls_16_snap[3]
cls_16_snap[30]
```

Comment: BTW: `sort` has lot of options to customize how it sorts. You man want to take a look at its manual page (e.g., via `man sort`).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$ sort -t'[' -nk2 file1
cls_16_snap[2]
cls_16_snap[3]
cls_16_snap[20]
cls_16_snap[21]
cls_16_snap[22]
cls_16_snap[23]
cls_16_snap[24]
cls_16_snap[25]
cls_16_snap[26]
cls_16_snap[27]
cls_16_snap[28]
cls_16_snap[29]
cls_16_snap[30]
```

`-n` option tell `sort` to compare numeric instead of string.